# How can i get the storage class of a object in Amazon S3 in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, amazon-s3, flysystem

I need to get the storage class of a object in a s3 bucket using the Laravel flysystem, but the class has no method, how can this be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project `thephpleague/flysystem-aws-s3-v3` needs updating to be more eloquent.

In Blade:

```
@php
   $as3StorageMetaData = ($as3Storage->getMetadata($file));
@endphp
```

In file loop use:

```
$as3StorageMetaData["storageclass"]
```

returns a constant.

This project could do with the function `getStorageClass`